# Embedded documents and arrays reduce need for expensive joins in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

> Embedded documents and arrays reduce need for expensive joins.

From: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/introduction/

What does that sentence mean? What documents are called embedded documents? How do they are arrays reduce need for expensive joins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1 would be a good read to understand embedding vs referencing techniques and what use cases they solve.

The quoted sentence itself says that nested documents are returned within a single fetch of the parent document which eliminates need to make fetches from multiple collections.

Nested / embedded / sub- documents are bson objects within an array property of the parent document. E.g.

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: "the doc",
    refs: [
        {name: "embedded document 1"},
        {name: "subdocument 2"},
        {value: { another: ["nested", "document"]}}
    ]
}
```

Compare it with references where `refs` are not embedded but stored in aseparate collection:

documents collection:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: "the doc",
}
```

referenced docs collection:

```
{doc_id: 1, name: "embedded document 1"},
{doc_id: 1, name: "subdocument 2"},
{doc_id: 1, value: { another: ["nested", "document"]}}
```

Fetching the doc with _id:1 and all referenced docs would require much more expensive query using aggregation framework with $lookup stage.